# How to create custom signal in ReactiveCocoa 4?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I have the following setup, a `GridView` that consists of `GridViewCell`s.

#### GridView

```
class GridView : UIView {

    var gridViewCells: [GridViewCell] = []
    let tapHandler: Position -> ()

    init(frame: CGRect, tapHandler: Position -> ()) {
        self.tapHandler = tapHandler
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.gridViewCells = createCells(self)
        addCellsToView(self.gridViewCells)
    }

    func addCellsToView(cells: [GridViewCell]) {
        for cell in cells {
            self.addSubview(cell)
        }
    }
}
```

#### GridViewCell

```
class GridViewCell: UIImageView {

    let position: Position
    let tapHandler: Position -> ()

    init(frame: CGRect, position: Position, tapHandler: Position -> ()) {
        self.position = position
        self.tapHandler = tapHandler
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.tapHandler(self.position)
    }    
}
```

Note that I omitted some less relevant parts of the code, just know that when creating the cells in `createCells()`, every cell gets a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that targets `handleTap:`, I am also using:

```
typealias Position = (Int, Int)
```

So, as you can see, whenever a `GridView` gets instantiated, it gets passed a callback function `tapHandler: Position -> ()` that ultimately gets called by the cell when a cell is tapped by the user.

Now, I want to turn the tap events into a RAC `Signal`. I have no clue how to approach this, as I am very new to RAC. Thanks to [Colin Eberhardts blog articles](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/04/24/first-look-reactive-cocoa-3.html), I managed to get a basic understanding of the building blocks and implement a custom signal like so:

```
func createSignal() -> Signal<String, NoError> {
    var count = 0
    return Signal {
        sink in
        NSTimer.schedule(repeatInterval: 1.0) { timer in
            sink.sendNext("tick #\(count++)")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

I now basically want a similar behaviour only that the emitted events aren't triggered by a `NSTimer`, but rather by the `handleTap()` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `Signal.pipe()`. This gives you a tuple with both the `signal`, and the `observer` tied to that signal:

```
let (signal, observer) = Signal<String, NoError>.pipe()
```

You can use that the same way you used `sink` in your example (note that `sink` is just the old terminology for `observer` :))

In the case of buttons or gesture recognizers though, you can leverage the `RAC 2` extensions. For example:

```
let signal: SignalProducer<(), NoError> = gestureRecognizer
   .rac_gestureSignal()
   .toSignalProducer()
   .mapError { fatalError("Unexpected error: \(error)"); return () } // errors cannot occur, but because they weren't typed in `RACSignal` we have to explicitly ignore them.
   .map { _ in () }
```

Or `UIControl.rac_signalForControlEvents`.

I published [a `gist`](https://gist.github.com/NachoSoto/25b0003c1b15d7d11a8d) with extensions to simplify some of these common operations. I hope that's useful!